# Setting The Text On A Custom Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I made a custom button with a custom image. Then I tried to set the title of it, but it didn't work. Here is the button's code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.49 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setTitle:@"DONE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBackOne) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;//hide original back button
}
```

But it still looks like this

[image]

Comment: If you don't set the image, do you get a button with the text you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the backgroundImage property if you want the image to appear underneath the text:

```
[backButton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you use the image property, the image will push the text out of the way (it works when you want to show a small image and text side by side)

Comment: Thanks, just figured it out an posted my answer when I saw yours :P

Comment: Do you know how to change the size of the font?

Comment: @Jonathan - try something like this: `button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:size];`

Answer (score 0):

Try `backButton.text = @"DONE"`.

**Edit:** Try changing this line:

`[backButton setTitle:@"DONE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

to

`[backButton setText:@"DONE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: I get the error Property 'text' not found on object of type 'UIButton *'